Older Sci-Fi/Fantasy animated movie?
What I can remember was that this was an OLD sci-fi/fantasy movie (I think I remember it being in 3D) and it had a female protagonist with some sort of tribal paint/tattooing on her. She did the typical restless and adventurous female character-shtick.
Anyway, she was super curious about the other side of the planet, but for whatever reason she never got there until much later in the movie. I do remember that she was shocked that the planet stopped and she nearly fell off the bottom which was made up of roots. All roots at the bottom.
And…well, that’s what I remember.
It wasn't a great movie, from what I remember, but I'm still super interested in re-watching it.

Can you remember an approximate year? I'm confused about it being old if it was in 3D, unless it was pretty famous and has been released. What is "typical restless and adventurous female character-shtick?" - can you give some examples? What was the plot of the film? Who was on the planet, how many people, what was their purpose? Anything you can remember would be helpful.

I'm sorry, I don't know the year of it. I know it was when 3D was still relatively new and so it would look poor in comparison to... say Monster's Inc, so it might be around that year or older.
And the "typical restless and adventurous female character" is basically: She runs around on the planet and doing death-defying leaps and bounds because she's fearless and know's her body's limits and so on. She has a rebellious streak when it comes to authority and is super curious about the other side of the planet, despite being told to not go there by her elders.

I don't remember all of the plot, otherwise Google would probably have given me an answer. I do remember that they ended up going to the other side of the planet, and found that it was just a bunch of roots and nearly fell off of it.
I do want to say that the title is most likely the girl's name or the planet's name and it sounded relatively "foreign" or "tribal" in nature.
I believe the cover was a picture of her. She had braids and beads in her hair.

I believe you are thinking of Kaena: The Prophecy (2003) (trailer) (DVD cover), the French-Canadian CG animated film about a race of people living on "Axis, a gigantic coiling plant [that] stretches high above the clouds." 
From Wikipedia: 

600 years later, a race of human-like tree-dwellers have evolved living in the branches of Axis. One of them, a young girl named Kaena (voiced by Kirsten Dunst), is an adventurous daydreamer who longs to explore the world beyond the confines of her village. Kaena's inquisitiveness is opposed as heresy by the village elder... 
...Kaena eventually defies the elder and climbs to the top of Axis. 

